# Numerical Reasoning EPSO Ratio Question

Tags: ratio

I would appreciate if anyone can please guide me on the workings to this question from the EPSO site.

[image: Table Data]

In 2000, what was the ratio of GDP in the Netherlands to that in Finland?

Possible Answers: 
    (a) 1:3 
    (b) 2:3
    (c) 3:2
    (d) 3:1
    (e) None of the above

---

My reasoning was as follows:

```
Netherlands GDP | Finland GDP   
=============== | ===========  
21003           | 21582
1               | 1.028
```

Which would make **(e) None of the above** the correct answer.

My problem is that another similar question resulted in the same answer and I am not sure whether my working is correct.

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 3:1.
You need to calculate the GDP per country and not per head (that they give you)
Of course you don't know the population of each country, but you already have the percent of the expenditure and the expenditure itself.
So:
for Netherlands 6075=(1.82*GDP1)/100

GDP1=333791.2 million Euros

For Finland 3725=(3.34*GDP2)/100

GDP2=111526.9 million Euros

GDP1/GDP2=2.99

Resulting a ratio of 3:1 by approximation :)

Thanks,

Sergiu